# fill gridbagconstraints not working properly?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

the cells of x other than the first will not take the extra space. I focused first on trying to fix the name parts, which now work but the 3-row part in the birthday section [image] 
is supposed to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocmCf.jpg)

I can't identify the logical error in here since I have followed the standard: set the fill to horizontal, set weights to 1, set gridwidth and update x and y.

```
    panelMain = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelMain);
    panelMain.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panelForm.setBackground(formColor);
    panelMain.add(panelForm); 

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,20);


    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    lblName = new JLabel("Name");
    panelForm.add(lblName, c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;     
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    txfFirst = new JTextField("First");   
    panelForm.add(txfFirst, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    txfLast = new JTextField("Last"); 
    panelForm.add(txfLast, c);

    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weightx = 1;
    lblEmail = new JLabel("Your email address");
    panelForm.add(lblEmail, c);

    c.gridy = 3;
    txfEmail = new JTextField();
    panelForm.add(txfEmail, c);

    c.gridy = 4;       
    lblPw = new JLabel("Create a password");
    panelForm.add(lblPw, c);

    c.gridy = 5;      
    pwfPw = new JPasswordField();
    panelForm.add(pwfPw, c);

    c.gridy = 6;
    lblConf = new JLabel("Confirm your password");
    panelForm.add(lblConf, c);

    c.gridy = 7;
    pwfConf = new JPasswordField();
    panelForm.add(pwfConf, c);

    c.gridy = 8;
    lblBday = new JLabel("Birthday");
    panelForm.add(lblBday, c);

    c.gridy = 9;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    cmbMonth = new JComboBox(months);
    panelForm.add(cmbMonth, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    txfDay = new JTextField("Day");
    panelForm.add(txfDay, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    txfYear = new JTextField("Year");
    panelForm.add(txfYear, c);

    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 10; 
    lblGend = new JLabel("Gender");
    panelForm.add(lblGend, c);

    c.gridy = 11;
    cmbGend = new JComboBox();
    panelForm.add(cmbGend,c );

    c.gridy = 12;
    lblPhone = new JLabel("Mobile phone");
    panelForm.add(lblPhone, c);

    c.gridy = 13;
    txfPhone = new JTextField();
    panelForm.add(txfPhone, c);

    c.gridy = 14;
    lblLoc = new JLabel("Location");
    panelForm.add(lblLoc, c);
    c.gridy = 15;

    cmbLoc = new JComboBox();
    panelForm.add(cmbLoc, c);
    c.gridy = 16;

    c.gridx = 2;
    btnNext = new JButton("Next Step");
    panelForm.add(btnNext, c);
```

Comment: How is your current code not working? How is your current GUI not as you desire? It isn't clear in your question text.  Please post less, "I have been stuck for hours" and more pertinent information that actually helps explain the code and your problem. In fact get rid of the "I have been stuck..." text as it only distracts.

Comment: The txfLast (and other components not on gridx 0) will not take the extra space even after setting the fill horizontal.

Comment: Shouldn't the contraints for that component have a gridwidth of `2` and not `1`? You've appear to have lines below that use multiple x positions.

Comment: Also you can set the column width for your JTextFields by using a constructor that accepts ints, such as `JTextField txfLast = new JTextField("Last", 10);`

Comment: It worked! I always changed the gridwidth as a group not individually. However, it doesnt seem to work on the 3-part row on the birthday section. The day is stuck being small even after using the weightx = 1

Comment: The 3-part row complicates things. Those guys would have a gridwidth of 1 and smaller column properties

Comment: Yes, I had them at gridwidth 1, but the space is still unbalanced. I also noticed that setting gridwidth 2 for the txfLast makes it way longer than the txfFirst.

Comment: That's because of your long 3 part row messing things up. You may want to get rid of it, or combine it into its own small JPanel and then add it to the GridBag JPanel using a width of 2, all other fields using a gridwidth of 1. Keep playing with things.

Comment: If this were my GUI, I'd create a column of JLabels followed by a column for data entry

Comment: I am tasked to replicate the google sign up form using java, doesn't need to be 100% though but im trying. But now I'm thinking if I were to put every information category in a gridbag jpanel (its label and input field) into a bigger jpanel with gridbag layout, would it be more effective?

Comment: Don't ask, try. Play with your code.